# Is there a way to use goclient to execute kubectl commands

Tags: kubectl, kubernetes-go-client

I want to get `kubectl get nodes` O/P using go code. I know there is GocLient to get the result but what I am looking for is pretty printed result just like how we get in CLI. Is there any wrapper code available for this requirement.